# How should I reference the institution in my grad school applications if I went to a satellite campus?

Tags: graduate-admissions, graduate-school

I go to a well respected University of X. However, I actually attend a campus that is smaller and separate from the main large campus. As I look at graduate schools and begin drafting my statement of purpose, should I specifically mention (every time) that I go to U of X, *City* campus, or just mention the university as a whole?

Comment: Why do you have to repeatedly refer to the university by name in your statement of purpose?

Comment: @BryanKrause Thanks, that made me think. Really, its because I spent time at a community college and at a large state university for undergrad. In my statement of purpose I wanted to distinguish my time before and after upper division, and explain the grade improvement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the rules and regulations are the same at both campuses, I doubt that you need to make a distinction. This is especially true if you would have been welcome to take classes at either campus without distinction.

But the university has an official name. If the satellite campus has a different *official* name you could, and maybe should, use that. But the "expanded" name may just be a geographic signifier without any official distinction other than geography. But you can ask the university for advice, of course.

My former university has several campuses in various cities in the same geographic region of the state. There is no distinction in the degrees offered and it is the university as a whole that grants them. The diploma shows no distinction. Is that the case at your institution?

Comment: thank you. At my institution it has no distinction of degrees. The program is slightly different, as at my satellite campus the program was built from the ground up. Also, though we have the opportunity to take classes on the main campus, it is usually impractical since they do have a bit of a drive between them, and we can only take a certain amount of classes on other campuses. My diploma will show no distinction. Thank you!